# How apache beam realize Scala zipWithIndex()?

Tags: apache-beam

Pcollection p1 = {"a","b","c"}

PCollection> p2 = p1.apply("some operation ") //{(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")}

How can I get the result by Apache Beam,Thanks?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416459/how-apache-beam-realize-scala-zipwithindex

Comment: I mean of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746046/how-can-i-implement-zipwithindex-like-spark-in-apache-beam